# Magento 1.9.2 - Optimize the search engine

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products, search, catalogsearch

When I write a word in my search bar the result is ever many items and I always find my searched product after many items.

To try to improve the search at the time I modified the file:

> app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Fulltext.php

replacing

> $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';

in

> $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';

After this I modified in configuration -> catalog -> catalog search -> type of search and i choice "Like".

Finally I made the reindex of catalog search. I tried again the search but always with the usual results. I still continue to view many products before seeing mine.

What else can I do?

Comment: Which version of 1.9?

Comment: The problem occurs on many products. Only a few products do not have this kind of problem. I saw the guide but in that topic we talk about version 1.9.3. My version is 1.9.2. Sorry I did not specify

Comment: If it's a version before, then it's safe to assume it still needs to be patched, correct? Have you tried to patch according to the other SO answer? If not, I recommend doing so.

Comment: Ok man thanks for the help. I try and let you know

Comment: @MagentoAaron I tried it but without results. Furthermore when i looked for the string "$this->getSelect()->orWhere('FALSE');" this did not exist in my file. Maybe because I have a previous version of magento compared to that expressed in the guide...Any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: I suggest carefully retracing your steps and try again. The solution is contained in the SO answer that this is a duplicate of.